# Adding a single cell to a Range in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Sub that dynamically selects a range of cells and then passes that range in to the Internal Rate of Return Formula. I need to have a single cell appended to the beginning of the range for the formula to work. See below:

```
Dim calcrange As Range
Set calcrange = Range(Range("B57"), Range("B57").End(xlToRight))

Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR(" & calcrange.Address & ")"
```

So ideally, what I'd like to do is add a named range cell "InvestmentOutlay" to be the first cell in the range. The InvestmentOutlay Cell is on a previous sheet, but the order I'd like the formula to run through is

```
=IRR(InvestmentOutlay,B57,C57, etc)
```

... Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using `Union` to join two ranges?

```
Set calcrange = Union(Range("InvestmentOutlay"), Range(Range("B57"), Range("B57").End(xlToRight)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Union' of object'_Global' failed." I'm new to VBA, so I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Do you have the named range `InvestmentOutlay` already set up?

Comment: Well I have it as a named range like in the excel sheet. Do I need to declare it as a variable or something in the VBA?

Comment: No. Should be fine. It's on the active sheet?

Comment: No, it's on the previous one. I thought when using a named range it would find it anywhere in the active workbook. Should I point it to the sheet InvestmentOutlay is on?

Comment: Oh. You can't really use `Union` in that way, over two sheets. There's probably a way to do what you're asking with it but because you're using `xlToRight` on your immediate sheet.

Comment: So I've been looking in to it ; It seems that "Union" can't join cells from different sheets. So I moved InvestmentOutlay to the Active sheet and the Sub runs without errors. The issue I now have is that when I look in the IRR formula, which _is_ returning an error, it shows "=IRR(A59,B57:G57)". Thanks for getting me this far, I think I'll just bump out a column for now and have it pull Investment Outlay with the other range.

Comment: Thanks CLR, I must have been typing when you replied. I very much appreciate your help!